# TRIGGER SQL TABLE RATE OF PARKING

Tags: mysql, database, triggers, sql-update, heidisql

- Avoid updating the rates if the value is lower or if it is higher than an increase of 10%.

[a part of my code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PITP0.png)

[Rate table columns.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLRWK.png)

For example:
1000 USD, the trigger must not allow to exceed 10% of the value. (is 100). Only go up to 1100 USD, but without being able to add more value. In the same way, but decreasing to 900.

Therefore, updates between 900 and 1100.

Comment: A question is far better if it has code, **as code**, included in the question, so that people can copy and paste and run the code. We don't need the typing practice for transcribing from pictures

Comment: Are you happy to silently ignore any update which would fall outwith acceptable bounds?

Comment: `IF NEW.balance/OLD.balance NOT BETWEEN 0.9 AND 1.1 THEN SIGNAL ...` - and avoid zero balance (how do you want to INSERT new row or UPDATE it from zero balance state?).